# How to make jest work with differently compiled Typescript in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

In my project I get the following from `yarn test`

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/danwt/Documents/work/interchain-security/diff-model-ts/node_modules/time-span/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import convertHrtime from 'convert-hrtime';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import * as fs from 'fs';
    > 2 | import timeSpan from 'time-span';
...
```

I have viewed many pages to try to find solutions and fix this without success.

My project is nodejs using typescript and jest.

```js
//jest.config.js
export default {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      useESM: true,
    },
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.(m)?js$': '$1',
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(m)?ts$',
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.ts',
    'src/**/*.mts',
    '!src/**/*.d.ts',
    '!src/**/*.d.mts',
  ],
};
```

```json
//package.json
{
  "name": "node-typescript-boilerplate",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Minimalistic boilerplate to quick-start Node.js development in TypeScript.",
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 16.13 <17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.4",
    "@types/node": "~16",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~5.26",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~5.26",
    "eslint": "~8.16",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "~8.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "~26.2",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "prettier": "~2.6",
    "rimraf": "~3.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.5",
    "tsutils": "~3.21",
    "typescript": "~4.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/src/main.js",
    "gen": "node build/src/gen.js",
    "clean": "rimraf coverage build tmp",
    "prebuild": "npm run lint",
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
    "build:watch": "tsc -w -p tsconfig.json",
    "build:release": "npm run clean && tsc -p tsconfig.release.json",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts --ext .mts",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "prettier": "prettier --config .prettierrc --write .",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  },
  "author": "Jakub Synowiec <jsynowiec@users.noreply.github.com>",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/clone-deep": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.4",
    "clone-deep": "^4.0.1",
    "time-span": "^5.1.0",
    "tslib": "~2.4",
    "underscore": "^1.13.4"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "16.13.0"
  }
}
```

```json
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "node16",
    "lib": [
      "ES2022"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "build",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "__tests__/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Here is the problematic file

```js
//node_modules/covert-hrtime/index.d.ts
export interface HighResolutionTime {
    seconds: number;
    milliseconds: number;
    nanoseconds: bigint;
}
export default function convertHrtime(hrtime: bigint): HighResolutionTime;
```

I have tried a lot of things including using `transformIgnorePatterns` and `transform` to match the problematic package in `jest.config.js`.

Can anybody spot the problem?

Thank you

Comment: just curious if you have gotten any further with this?  I have a similar problem.  I added a type to a constructor and now I get the same error running my test

Comment: Yes! What worked is including another (copy) tsconfig.json inside `__tests__ /`. It's a hack. I saw it suggested elsewhere on SO (I forgot where). Good luck. LMK if it works.